# Ajax custom button pass parameters in jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

**JS**

I'm new to Ajax.I have a jQuery dataTable for an RoR app.I have to pass parameters to the button so that I can choose the action to be performed when the button is clicked.

```js
var invoiceTable = $('#invoice_list_index').DataTable( {
    "scrollY": "300px",
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
          {
              extend: 'alert',
              text: 'My button 1',
          },
          {
              extend: 'alert',
              text: 'My button 2'
          },
          {
              extend: 'alert',
              text: 'My button 3'
          }
      ],
    "ajax": {
      type: "POST",
      url: '/invoices/invoice_index_page',
      
    }
  });
```

```html
<a class="dt-button buttons-alert" tabindex="0" aria-controls="invoice_list_index" href="#"><span>My button 1</span></a>
```

The problem is I don't know how to pass the parameter to the ajax custom button.

Comment: What parameters do you want to pass to these buttons actions ? Are those table row data or some other ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have included jQuery or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo :**  https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/7v7xLaz2/1/

Well first thing you need to do is create the actions for your `DataTable buttons`.

Please create your buttons like below.

```
"dom": 'Bfrtip',
   "buttons": [
          {
              text: 'My button 1',
              action: function () {
                console.log("inside button 1");
              }
          },
          {   
              text: 'My button 2',
              action: function () {
                console.log("inside button 2");
              }
          },
          {
              text: 'My button 3',
              action: function () {
                console.log("inside button 3");
              }
          }
      ]
```

So when you click on any of the button corresponding message will print.

So now second thing passing parameters to these buttons are like any other normal buttons just use the variables inside the action of corresponding button.